# How to set the value of a column to -1 (minus one) without performing the operation

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table where I have an integer column that I want to use php to set to -1. **But the problem is that** anytime I do

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE mytable SET mycolomn='-1' ") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

It does not set it to minus one "-1", rather I sets it to 0. I need the number in that field to be changed to minus one "-1" without it been set to 0.

I have tried to change the column to Decimal but still the same problem.

Comment: If you're trying to set the value to -1 in your "decimal" column you should not put it in quotes. In quotes you're putting the string "-1" into a decimal column.

Comment: @BigScar - it'll be parsed correctly by mysql as-is.

Comment: @sam I slightly misunderstood the question when I wrote that and I haven't been able to run a test to be sure (which I'm not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your table to see what type of INT you have.  An UNSIGNED INT cannot be negative.

```
Type          Storage         Min           Max
INT                 4 -2147483648    2147483647
INT UNSIGNED        4           0    4294967295
```